# QWizard with pagelist on the left

Tags: qt

I have a Qt QWizard in my project. I want it to have a pagelist with titles of my wizard pages. Also I want in this pagelist current page to be somehow checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a widget which has a QListWidget on the left and a QWizard on the right.

The list widget shows a list of all available pages (use [QWizard::pageIds](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwizard.html#pageIds)) of the wizard and every time a page is changed ([QWizard::currentIdChanged](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwizard.html#currentIdChanged)) you update the check state of each item in the list, using [QWizard::visitedPages](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwizard.html#visitedPages) which gives you a list of IDs of the pages which were already visited.

Remember that for the items in the list widget you have to manually set the flag `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable`.

> QList QWizard::visitedPages () const
>   Returns the list of IDs of visited pages, in the order in which the pages were visited.
>   Pressing Back marks the current page as "unvisited" again.

Answer (score 0):

Everything written below is relevant for Qt 5.15.

First of all, I have not created a widget that includes a wizard and a list, as @Exa wrote. I just add list widget as side for wizard with method [QWizard::setSideWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#setSideWidget):

```
listPages = new QListWidget;
// Also added a flag that the list item cannot be selected
listPages->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode::NoSelection);
setSideWidget(listPages);
```

And secondly i have defined a slot for the signal [QWizard::currentIdChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html#currentIdChanged) where I can change color and whatever to change the view of the list:

```
connect(this, &Wizard::currentIdChanged, this, &Wizard::OnPageIdChanged);
...
// To change listwidget states
void Wizard::OnPageIdChanged(int id)
{
// Do whatever you want with QListWidget
}
```